# AngularJS Unit Test Issue: Injecting $location

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, location

I am having an issue with testing a routeProvider. There seems to be a lot of information out there, but everything I do, I just cannot get the unit test to digest the location. I was hoping to find some closure here.  I am feeling my way through angularJS and unit testing, and could use any advice.

Here is the routeProvider function:

```
use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myServices',
  'myControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('fooBar', {
        templateUrl: 'barFoo',
        controller: 'SummaryCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'defaultFooBar'
      });

  }]);
```

I am trying to test this routeProvider with the following, but I cannot, for the life of my, inject the change I make to location.

```
'use strict';

describe('myApp',function() {
    var $scope;
    var location;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $location) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        location = $location;
    }));

    it('redirect to default', function() {
      location.path('efipoejs');
      $scope.$apply();
      expect(location.path()).toBe('defaultFooBar');
    })
});
```

Ive tried $scope.$digest, and .$apply.... what ever I do, I always get this outcome:

```
Expected '/efipoejs' to be 'defaultFooBar'.
```

I really want angularJS to work... If you have any advice that might lead me down the right path...I would seriously appreciate it.

**ANSWER: BECAUSE I CANT POST AN ANSWER WITHIN 8 HOURS!!!!**

yo yea,...

Here's how I got this to work

```
describe('Testing routes', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var location, route, rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(
        function( $location, $route, $rootScope ) {
            location = $location;
            route = $route;
            rootScope = $rootScope;
        }));

    describe('Default Routing', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(
            function($httpBackend) {
                $httpBackend.expectGET('DefaultUrl').respond(200);
            }));

        it('should load the default page on fake path', function() {
            location.path('/ermagerd');
            rootScope.$digest();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('defaultFooBar');
        });

        });
    });
});
```

Once again, here is my logic

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myServices',
  'myControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('fooBarDefault', {
        templateUrl: 'defaultUrl',
        controller: 'DefaultCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'fooBarDefault'
      });

  }]);
```

Comment: Have you loaded your module before running the test? `beforeEach(module('myApp'))`?

Comment: `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`  I added that line before the other beforeEach... seems to have the same effect, not getting the output I expect to get.

Comment: This might be calling for an integration test. Not sure...

Comment: @AlexC Can you expand on that? e2e.. I havent done too much research into e2e, but if thats the route I need to take, I will gladly go down that path.

Comment: You might be able to unit test but I think E2E will address this part of the code better. I am not an expert either so I am not comfortable telling you how to do that e2e. Hopefully, you ll get a more complete answer soon.

Comment: @AlexC Thanks Alex. I'm going to look down that path right now. I will post my answer if I do get this logic to test properly.

Comment: well, i figured it out. I cant post my answer until 8 hours after posting, maybe ill just throw it in the op

Comment: So, the `$httpBackend` is required?